# REST API MARKETO - Emails - publishToMSI

Tags: rest, api, publish, marketo

Can you tell me why this isn't working :

/rest/asset/v1/emails.json?publishToMSI=true

or

/rest/asset/v1/emails.json?publishToMSI=1

When I use one or the other Marketo retrieve the email but the selection on publishToMSI does not work. How can I make it work ? 
Here the documentation :
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/emails/#browse

And the detail of the API Call
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/asset-endpoint-reference/#!/Emails/getEmailUsingGET

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter publishToMSI. It is an attribute in the response though. When you 'browse' Emails, you get all of them and you need to filter them after you receive them.